# Trouble on checking of image existing on remote server in Chrome browser by using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, xmlhttprequest

I use this JQuery method on page to check if image exists:

```
function imageExists(imageUrl) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', imageUrl, false);
  http.send();
  return http.status !== 404;
}
```

If I load the page in browser, it works great, but if I go to the next page and then go back to this page the script does not work correctly. There is error in browser console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://server/image.jpg' from origin 'http://client' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This error occurs only when I back from another site page to this page in Chrome browser. There is no error in Firefox and Edge browsers

Thanks!!!

Comment: That error should be there in either case, CORS does not depend on whether you navigate back and forth between your own pages, but solely on whether the remote host allows this kind of request, or not.

Comment: I know and CORS is enabled on Server with images. Maybe CORS policy is set not correctly on remote server. But why it works without errors on loading page?

Comment: Then the response should show the appropriate headers in the network panel; does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by adding request header of 'Cache-Control' with 'no-cache' value:

```
function imageExists(imageUrl) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', imageUrl, false);
    http.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    http.send();

    return http.status !== 404;
}
```